# Pointing domain based on port?

Tags: dns, webserver, xmpp, port

I was wondering if I could have a domain change where it's pointed to based upon the port the program requests. My specific need is to point a web server and a XMPP server to two different servers using the same domain.

I have example.com for web and example.com for XMPP
Web uses port 80 , which I assume browsers call automatically, and XMPP uses ports 5222, 5223, 9090, and 7070 which I know is called automatically by the XMPP client I've compiled.

So from what I gather they both hit the DNS first and then get directed to IP (example) 555.555.555.555 since I currently have both web and XMPP in the same location. I want the web to hit the DNS I get pointed to 123.123.123.123 and XMPP to get 555.555.555.555 , but on the client end still just see example.com .

If what I am asking for is unclear just ask a question back and I will try to be more specific. I appreciate all your time and help on this matter!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you just need to change your SRV record for XMPP to a different host. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record , edit: more infos on SRV/XMPP here: http://blog.teemu.im/2008/12/14/setting-your-srv-records-straight-for-xmpp/

Answer (score 1):

HTTP web clients will *only* use port 80 (or 443 for `https`) by default, i.e. unless specified explicitly in the URL[*]

Any conformant XMPP (jabber) server will attempt to look up an `SRV` record for:

`_xmpp-client._tcp`*`.yourdomain.com`*

per section 3.2.1 of [RFC 6120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-3.2.1), so just create a secondary *hostname* for your XMPP server, and then put that hostname (and your server's port) in your SRV records.

[*] There has been discussion at the IETF about using SRV records for HTTP too, but it hasn't really got anywhere.

Comment: "Only" is strong here for HTTP.  Of course you can do `http://example.com:8000/` as a URL.

Comment: @Joe that's what I mean by 'by default', i.e. unless specified in the URL. I've clarified the text.

Comment: @Joe p.s. thanks for updating the reference - shame on me for not noticing that 3920 had been obsoleted...

Comment: @Alnitak

So if I just make an SRV record for example.com pointing to IP X and leave the A records and the rest of them as "Stock" , it should work?

Comment: @Reizvoller no, you have to make a new hostname first and then point the SRV record at that - you can't put an IP address directly in an SRV record.